# modelling a curve on a mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a curve on a shape, The topology seems clean, all quads, but when adding the subsurface modifier, the edges are not curving as expected. They are jagged from the outside side of the line. Although the inner part of the curve seems clean that particular edge is causing the mesh to look more rectangular and projecting the edge. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hey :). You need to distribute the vertices more evenly. The closer are vertices together the sharper the corners. It has nothing to do with quads.

Comment: it appears the rounded edges are only on one side of this cubic shape. I.e. it is not going through and cutting to the other side, this will not work with the subdiv mod

Comment: I managed after some methods to get a result, so I used the inset method and it worked great. the problem which caused not to have a nice symmetric curve was I was using loop cuts. 

Here's the image: https://ibb.co/9TkG4kR

Comment: Can you please create your own answer including the details of your findings? This way everyone benefits it!

Comment: Here is the Tutorial. Hope it helps.

https://ibb.co/R9RZG0S

I don't know how long the hosting website will keep the link for though, so download it if you need to keep it.

Kind regards.